# A problem about coset and transversal.

Tags: group-theory, transversality

For a finite group $G$ and its subgroup $H$. Show that there is a subset $T$ which is simultaneously a transversal for the left and right cosets of $H$.

Further ,if we consider any two partition of $G$,and the sets have the same cardinality.Can we find a transversal for both of them?

I get the answer as the comments tell me how to do it.Considerating the left cosets as point in left,and right cosets in right.Two points are adjacent when they are in different sides and have common elements.Then I realized that if there exists a complement match,then I can prove it.The condition of Hall's theorem is easy to be seen as it will lead to a controdiction of the cardinality as they are partitions with the sets of same cardinality.

However,when it comes to the sitiation of infinte cardinality of  G,what can we say about it?

Comment: Use Hall's theorem.

Comment: I tried it just now.Considerating the left cosets as point in left,and right cosets in right.Two points are adjacent when they are in different sides and have common elements.Then I realized that  if there exists a complement match,then I can prove it.But I don't konw how to prove the condition of Hall's theorem.

Comment: @Hugo please [edit] that information into your question.

Comment: The condition of Hall's theorem is easy to show. Think about it more.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268219/mutual-set-of-representatives-for-left-and-right-cosets-what-about-infinite-gro) has an interesting discussion of the general case, when $G$ is allowed to be infinite.

Comment: Sorry for too late,as I failed to log in for a long time.Now I konw how to do it when I just consider about the proposition of partion,and overlook the detail about group..Thanks for your hint.I will edit my question and post my answer later.

Comment: Could you please say somthing about the infinite situation?@Andreas Caranti

Comment: There is a common transversal for the left and right cosets provided that the subgroup $H$ is either finite or of finite index in $G.$